# For loop and 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I am learning Javascript and I am confused about for loops. I don't know how to loop through 2 arrays and to print one value from each array concatenated together. I tried solving the below problem, but it does not work. What would be the best way to solve this. Thanks for your help!

```
var nums = [1, 5, 88, 2, 5, 42, 57, 101]
var nouns = ["ducks", "telephone booth", "the enterprise", "robots", "amazon", "eraser", "zafod", "a"]

// output of the first function should be: "1 ducks"
for (let i=0; i.nums.length; i++)
    console.log(nums[i].concat(nouns[i]));
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Loop Condition**

Your for loop condition is causing an error. The [syntax of a for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for) states that the second item ("loop condition") should evaluate to a boolean (`true`/`false`) value that tells you when to continue iterating and when to stop.

Right now you have "`i.nums.length`" as your loop condition, which isn't valid code (since the number stored in the variable `i` doesn't have a property `nums`).

Instead, you should have `i < nums.length` as your loop condition, which will be `true` until `i` is no longer a valid index in the `nums` array, at which point it is `false` and the loop stops.

**Concatenating Output**

Numbers don't have a "`concat`" method, so you can't do  `nums[i].concat()`. To concatenate a number with a string in javascript, you can use `+`, which will convert the number to a string and concatenate it to the string. If you want a space, you can concatenate that as well.

**Checking Lengths**

If `nouns.length` is less than `nums.length`, Javascript will produce `undefined` for the missing items of `nouns`, but not throw an error. To make sure that the two arrays are the same length before iterating over them, you can use `console.assert(nouns.length === nums.length, message)` to print an error message if the lengths don't match exactly. This isn't strictly required (since the lengths *do* match in your sample code) but makes the code more robust to mistakes in the array declarations.

**Final Code**

The final code (with all modifications) looks like this:

```
var nums = [1, 5, 88, 2, 5, 42, 57, 101];
var nouns = ["ducks", "telephone booth", "the enterprise", "robots", "amazon", "eraser", "zafod", "a"];
console.assert(nums.length === nouns.length, `Array sizes ${nums.length} and ${nouns.length} don't match`);

// output of the first function should be: "1 ducks"
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    console.log(nums[i] + " " + nouns[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should check that both arrays are the same size to avoid unintentional errors. Enclose the for loop in an if statement if (nums.length === nouns.length) {...}

Comment: I've added an assertion to check that the lengths match. I'm not sure that enclosing the loop in an if statement is the best way to avoid that class of errors, since it replaces one silent failure (printing `undefined`s) with another (not printing anything at all), but it does seem reasonable to include the check.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple errors in your code.

`i.nums.length` should be `i < nums.length`

[concat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp) works only with Strings, so first you need to convert `nums[i]` value to a string and then use `str1.concat(str2)` OR you can simple use `+` between `nums[i]` and `nouns[i]` which is simpler approach like this: `nums[i] + " " + nouns[i]`

Below is working code, have a look:

```js
var nums = [1, 5, 88, 2, 5, 42, 57, 101]
var nouns = ["ducks", "telephone booth", "the enterprise", "robots", "amazon", "eraser", "zafod", "a"]

// output of the first function should be: "1 ducks"
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  console.log(nums[i] + " " + nouns[i]);
}
```

Comment: As stated in the comment, "1 ducks" instead of  "1ducks", I believe you missed out a space and `toString` is unnecessary since an extra space needed

Comment: @Isaac thanks for pointing out regarding "1 ducks" instead of "1ducks" but `toString()` is required. Because the purpose here is not just giving any alternate solution to user but giving him correct solution in whatever he is using. I have explained why `concat` is not working and then mentioned how to make it work. Hope it make sense.

Comment: What I was trying to meant is, as we needed a space between 1 and ducks hence we can apply type coercion just like the answer stated by `Ollin Boer Bohan`. I wasn't saying it was wrong, just unnecessary or maybe just a fond of style

Comment: @Isaac ah ok. Got it. Updated. Please have a look!